# Parsing to HTML using XML and PHP

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to parse an XML feed by using PHP and I keep getting errors,

```
 <?php
     $html = simplexml_load_file('http://api.hotukdeals.com/rest_api/v2/?key=6948de072326c21e9f7c76b2a153e49a&merchant=tesco-com-and-in-store&online_offline=offline&order=new&forum=deals&results_per_page=10');

 foreach ($html as $dealinfo):
         $api_item=$dealinfo->title;
 endforeach;

 ?>
```

Can anyone help where I may be going wrong with this?

Heres the link to the page.

http://simpleclassifieds.co.uk/deal.php

Comment: The URL you're trying to fetch from is wrong. Visit in your browser - it's a 404 page.

Comment: Does that url return a valid xml document..?

Comment: ok, I've updated the code with the correct url.

    <?php
        $html = simplexml_load_file('http://api.hotukdeals.com/rest_api/v2/?key=6948de072326c21e9f7c76b2a153e49a&merchant=tesco-com-and-in-store&online_offline=offline&order=new&forum=deals&results_per_page=10');
   

 

    
    foreach ($html as $dealinfo):

            $title=$dealinfo->title;

    
        endforeach;


    ?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your foreach loop should be like this

```
foreach ($html->deals->api_item as $dealinfo):
        echo $dealinfo->title."<br />";
 endforeach;
```

Comment: super, that makes much more sense now.

Thanks!!

Comment: This answer is only useful for the person asking the question and carries no or only little information for future visitors. It might have been an improvement to not answer the question at all but to direct to a reference question instead.